# Concatenating with empty numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am running into errors when concatenating arrays in Python:

```
x = np.array([])
while condition:
    % some processing 
    x = np.concatenate([x + new_x])
```

The error I get is:

```
----> 1 x = np.concatenate([x + new_x])

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (6)
```

On a side note, is this an efficient way to grow a `numpy` array in Python?

Comment: Given that you're copying `x` on every iteration, I am not sure I would necessarily call this "efficient".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to call

```
x = np.concatenate((x, new_x))
```

according to [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: Also, for greater control, there are the functions `hstack`, `vstack` and `dstack`, that are worth taking a look!

Comment: @heltonbiker How do those have greater control than `concatenate`? I thought `concatenate` can do an arbitrary axis, whereas `hstack`, `vstack`, and `dstack` concatenate along a particular axis.

Comment: By "greater control" I meant that, say, with `hstack` you always will concatenate along 1-axis. So, using `hstack` you won't "accidentally" concatenate along the wrong axis, so you would in this sense be more "in control" of the situation. But in the end it's a matter of perspective, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
x = np.append(x,new_x)
```

Regarding your side note, take a look here: [How to extend an array in-place in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215525/how-to-extend-an-array-in-place-in-numpy)