# Creating a defaultdict with empty numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, collections, defaultdict

I'm wondering if there's a more clever way to create a default dict from collections.
The dict should have an empty numpy ndarray as default value.

My best result is so far:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: numpy.ndarray(0))
```

However, i'm wondering if there's a possibility to skip the lambda term and create the dict in a more direct way. Like:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(numpy.ndarray(0))  # <- Nice and short - but not callable
```

Comment: Why do you want to use ndarray with defaultdict? You'll have to create a new array each time to insert an item to an existing key, better use list which supports append operation.

Comment: `np.concat()` can be used to accumulate arrays.  If the arrays are large and few, this may be more efficient.  So, I like the proposed solution above.

Comment: Accumulation: `base = defaultdict(lambda : np.ndarray(0)); base = np.concatenate((base, new_array)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial()` instead of a lambda:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

defaultdict(partial(numpy.ndarray, 0))
```

You *always* need a callable for `defaultdict()`, and `numpy.ndarray()` *always* needs at least one argument, so you cannot just pass in `numpy.ndarray` here.

Comment: I'm new to Numpy. Is Ashwini correct when he says 'You'll have to create a new array each time to insert an item to an existing key. Better use list which supports append operation'?

Comment: @Phillip yes, they are correct. Numpy arrays have a fixed size; see [How to extend an array in-place in Numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13215525).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is the following if you know the array size beforehand:

```
new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: numpy.zeros(array_size))
```