# View on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix

```
 m = np.zeros((5,5))
```

and what to have a view on the last row

```
row = m[-1]
```

however if I add a column to m:

```
m = np.c_[m[:,:2],[0,0,1,1,1],m[:,2:]]
```

and print out row I don't get the new column.

Is there any way to get the change without use the line

```
row = m[-1]
```

again?

Comment: You want to modify your previous array in an in-place manner and that's not possible. Every time you change your array you'll end up creating a new object.

Comment: The question should be: "Why do you need to do that?" it makes no sense to me

Comment: I think maybe the problem lies in the method `np.c_`, which is different from ordinary operation on view of Numpy array, which can achieve in-place modification.

Comment: @ManelFornos I have a simplex tableau in m and would like to get the objective row (last row) sometimes I need to add columns to the matrix.

Comment: you want to get last row without running this `row = m[-1]` each time?

Comment: @MedAli I want that row updates itself whenever there is a change of m in anyway but as Kasramvd said: It has to be inline for that

Comment: `c_` is a `concatenate` function.  It makes a new array with copies of data from `m`.  The fact that you assign it to the variable `m` does not create any connection to `row` or other view of the original.  Updating the reference to the last row of `m` is the responsibility of your code.  It's not a  time expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve here isn't currently possible within the bounds of the `numpy` library.
See this answer on [numpy arrays occupying a contiguous block of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215559/5189811).

You can use the `rx` library to get around this by making a subject of the last row.

```
import numpy as np
from rx import Observable, Observer
from rx.subjects import Subject

m = np.zeros((5,5))

m_stream = Subject()
last_row_stream = Subject()
last_row = None

def update_last(v):
    global last_row
    last_row = v

last_row_stream.subscribe(on_next=update_last)
last_row_stream.on_next(m[-1])

print(last_row)

m_stream.map(
    lambda v: np.insert(v, 2, [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], axis=1)
).subscribe(lambda v: last_row_stream.on_next(v[-1]))

m_stream.on_next(m)


print(last_row)
```

Comment: I thought of an observer pattern as well. I would like to observe on every change made so whenever `m` changed I would like to have `row` changed. Doesn't matter whether it really changed row or not. 
Therefore I would like to not change the `insert` or `c_` row. Would like to have a subscribe to all changes of `m`.

Comment: `m_stream` is an observable of `m`. Any operations you want to carry out on `m` can be mapped on `m_stream` for a start. You can also dispose of observer(s) whenever you deem it fit. `...subscribe(lambda v: last_row_stream.on_next(v[-1]))` sets a observer on `m_stream` that updates `last_row_stream`. You can dispose of this and set your very own observer.