# Overwriting an object inside if-condition

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, scope

I have a method, where I have an object (numpy.ndarray) and I want to edit it inplace (add some more columns for example) and a list of column names that are allowed to be concatenated to the ndarray object.

Here is an outline of the method, after I sort the columns passed to the method in two lists:

```
def my_method(object, list_of_columns):
 
# sort list_of_columns into two lists with allowed and not allowed cols

if cols_not_allowed:  # if the list with not allowed columns not empty 
   print(f"These columns {cols_not_allowed} are not allowed")

if cols_allowed: # if the list with allowed columns not empty
   # overwrite/edit the nd_array object
```

My problem is that the object which I pass to my method wouldn't update outside of the function. I do not return anything here and do not want to, I just want to call this function to update my object inplace, without any copying. I can see the wanted changes in the function itself, but I don't see them when calling `my_method(obj, ["blabla", "haha"])` somewhere else.

Comment: We can't help without knowing something about this `object`, and how you are editing it.

Comment: @hpaulj I am appending columns to numpy.ndarray that were previously saved somewhere else with according names that I am passing to the method (hence allowed and not allowed cols).

Comment: Using `np.append`?  List append works in-place.  You cannot do the same with an array.  Read the function docs.  Any time you do something like `arr = function(arr)` you are overwriting that `arr`, not modifying it in-place.

Comment: You need to understand what the 'modification' method is doing.  Placing it in an `if` clause isn't the issue here.

Comment: @hpaulj okay, so the `if`clause is not isolating my code snippet ie object being modified?

Comment: It seems you can't expand a numpy array in-place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215525/how-to-extend-an-array-in-place-in-numpy

Comment: Review basic Python handling of variables in a function.  https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python